# Error conexion mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código. Parece que no se cierra la conexión o da algún error. El error que muestra es:

> Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli_close in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\new\89_Blog1\insertarContenido.php on line 23
>
> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\new\89_Blog1\insertarContenido.php on line 23

```
<?php
$miconexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdBlog");
if(!$miconexion){
    echo "La conexión ha fallado: ". error();
    exit();
}
    $mysqli_close($miconexion);

?>
```

¿A que se debe el error?

Comment: `$mysqli_close($miconexion);` al tener el `$` delante lo toma como una variable , debe ser sin `$` , es decir `mysqli_close($miconexion);`

Comment: Aah, claro. Mil gracias.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quita el `$` de la función `mysqli_close($miconexión)`

```
<?php
$miconexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bdBlog");
if(!$miconexion){
    echo "La conexión ha fallado: ". error();
    exit();
}
mysqli_close($miconexion);

?>
```